# Forming tracks of coordinates depending on distance

Tags: list-manipulation, nearest

I have a list that consists of certain number of coordinates sub-lists (here 8).

(The following data are only an example to describe my problem.)

```
list={
{1,{{1.00,1.00},{2.00,2.00},{3.00,3.00},{4.00,4.00},{5.00,5.00}}},
{2,{{2.01,2.01},{3.01,3.01},{1.01,1.01},{5.01,5.01},{4.01,4.01}}},
{3,{{1.02,1.02},{3.02,3.02},{4.02,4.02},{6.02,6.02},{5.02,5.02}}},
{4,{{7.00,7.00},{1.03,1.03},{6.03,6.03}}},
{5,{{1.50,1.50},{4.04,4.04},{6.04,6.04},{7.04,7.04}}},
{6,{{1.51,1.51},{4.05,4.05},{7.03,7.03},{6.05,6.05}}},
{7,{{2.50,2.50},{7.00,7.00},{5.01,5.01},{4.03,4.03},{8.01,8.01}}},
{8,{{2.51,2.51},{6.00,6.00},{7.01,7.01},{4.04,4.04},{8.02,8.02}}}
};
```

Each coordinate sub-list can have a different length.

Depending on the next-neareast coordinate between neighboured sub-lists (which should be below a certain threshold distance, here I assume 0.2) the `list` should be reformed, so that `tracks` is obtained.

```
tracks={
{{1,{1.,1.}},{2,{1.01,1.01}},{3,{1.02,1.02}},{4,{1.03,1.03}}},
{{1,{2.,2.}},{2,{2.01,2.01}}},{{1,{3.,3.}},{2,{3.01,3.01}},{3,{3.02,3.02}}},
{{1,{4.,4.}},{2,{4.01,4.01}},{3,{4.02,4.02}}},
{{1,{5.,5.}},{2,{5.01,5.01}},{3,{5.02,5.02}}},
{{3,{6.02,6.02}},{4,{6.03,6.03}},{5,{6.04,6.04}},{6,{6.05,6.05}}},
{{4,{7.,7.}},{5,{7.04,7.04}},{6,{7.03,7.03}},{7,{7.,7.}},{8,{7.01,7.01}}},
{{5,{1.5,1.5}},{6,{1.51,1.51}}},
{{5,{4.04,4.04}},{6,{4.05,4.05}},{7,{4.03,4.03}},{8,{4.04,4.04}}},
{{7,{2.5,2.5}},{8,{2.51,2.51}}},
{{7,{5.01,5.01}}},
{{7,{8.01,8.01}},{8,{8.02,8.02}}},
{{8,{6.,6.}}}
}
```

**Please use (also for speed testing) a set of some real data which are available here: https://pastebin.com/rEzbC1kH.**

Since I am not experienced enough with mathematica the only way what I can do is to use a do loop and then compare each coordinate of sub-list `i` `(1=<i<=8)` with the coordinates of sub-list `i+1`, determine the corresponding nearest neighbour (always only one is existing) and then continute this way ...

How would you solve this?

Background information:

I am using a high speed camera and recording laser illuminated dust-like particles in a plasma. They all usually have a nearly constant spacing whereby they randomly move in small steps around their mean positions (step width << mean particle distance). During the observation time some can be lost since they move out of the laser beam and others can appear. One main part after finding the objects coordinates is to track them in time. The problem (“object/particle detection and tracking”) is very important e.g. in physics, biology and medicine.

In Matlab, Python (here trackpy is very famous) and IDL there are many (sophisticated) solutions for this problem, but until now I did not find anything in mathematica which solves this problem. I am surprised about that because mathematica is very strong in images analysis as well in list operations.

Example movie:

[image]

Comment: Is there a typo in line 3 of `list` where `6.01` should be `6.02`? Also, in `tracks`, shouldn't `{7,{7.00,7.00}` and `{8,{7.01,7.01}}` be on the line starting with `{4,{7.00,7.00}}`?

Comment: @Edmund: thanks, absolutely true ... and this corresponds then to the correct track which m_goldberg obtained in the list clusters ...

Comment: What happened to the two entries of {4.04, 4.04} in line 5?

Comment: @Carl Woll: this is an error, one of them should be deleted (I removed the last one) ... and corrected the tracks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a possibility:

```
getTracks[list_, threshold_] := Block[{ind, next},
    ind = Range @ Length[list[[1, 2]]];
    next = Length[ind] + 1;
    Last @ Reap[
        MapIndexed[Sow[{1, list[[1, 2, First@#2]]}, #]&, ind];

        Do[
            n = newIndex @ Nearest[
                list[[i-1, 2]] -> {"Index","Distance"},
                list[[i,2]],
                {1, threshold}
            ];
            MapIndexed[Sow[{i, list[[i, 2, First@#2]]}, #]&, n],
            {i, 2, Length[list]}
        ],
        _,
        #2&
    ]
]

toIndex[{}] := next++
toIndex[{{a_Integer,_}}] := toIndex[a]
toIndex[a_Integer] := ind[[a]]

newIndex[list_] := With[{old=toIndex/@list}, ind = old]
```

Basically, I use [`Reap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap)/[`Sow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sow) to collect points, and I use [`Nearest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nearest) between neighboring sublists to figure out which index the new point should be sown to. Here is `getTracks` applied to your dataset:

```
getTracks[list, .2]

{
{{1, {1., 1.}}, {2, {1.01, 1.01}}, {3, {1.02, 1.02}}, {4, {1.03, 1.03}}},
{{1, {2., 2.}}, {2, {2.01, 2.01}}},
{{1, {3., 3.}}, {2, {3.01, 3.01}}, {3, {3.02, 3.02}}},
{{1, {4., 4.}}, {2, {4.01, 4.01}}, {3, {4.02, 4.02}}},
{{1, {5., 5.}}, {2, {5.01, 5.01}}, {3, {5.02, 5.02}}},
{{3, {6.02, 6.02}}, {4, {6.03, 6.03}}, {5, {6.04, 6.04}}, {6, {6.05, 6.05}}},
{{4, {7., 7.}}, {5, {7.04, 7.04}}, {6, {7.03, 7.03}}, {7, {7., 7.}}, {8, {7.01, 7.01}}},
{{5, {1.5, 1.5}}, {6, {1.51, 1.51}}},
{{5, {4.04, 4.04}}, {6, {4.05, 4.05}}, {7, {4.03, 4.03}}, {8, {4.04, 4.04}}},
{{5, {4.04, 4.04}}},
{{7, {2.5, 2.5}}, {8, {2.51, 2.51}}},
{{7, {5.01, 5.01}}},
{{7, {8.01, 8.01}}, {8, {8.02, 8.02}}},
{{8, {6., 6.}}}
}
```

Notice that the one issue is what to do with repeated points, like happens in line 5 of `list`. The above code creates two tracks, one for each duplicated point.

Comment: This is great ...  thanks. I have removed the (wrong) double coordinate in line 5 and have corrected the output according to the result of your code https://i.imgur.com/Cli8Mqf.png.

Comment: Very fast solution: about 0.01 sec for my real data example: https://pastebin.com/rEzbC1kH) ... I successively increased the threshold from 0.1 to 50 and the number of tracks converges to the mean number of available coordinates per sub-set (443, see first comment to m_goldbergs solution), which is what I expected. For checking of the tracks I plotted them with `tracks=getTracks[list, threshold]; ListLinePlot[tracks[[#, All, 2]] & /@ Range@Length@tracks]` and they look very good.

Comment: I have tested the code with data consisting of 10 000 images and 1600 particles per image.

The duration for finding the longest tracks is 94 sec (resulting in 1600 tracks, each 10 000 images long) - this is perfect. Thanks again a lot for your help. 

May be you can trigger a talk about this in one of the next Wolfram  Technology Conferences.

Comment: Could you please have a look on that question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/189592/removing-anomalous-points-from-data

Answer (score 4):

You might try `ClusterClassify`. It seems to work well for your example data. It gives a somewhat different clustering than you give, but its clustering actually looks better to me.

```
rawData = 
  {{1, {{1.00, 1.00}, {2.00, 2.00}, {3.00, 3.00}, {4.00, 4.00}, {5.00, 5.00}}}, 
   {2, {{2.01, 2.01}, {3.01, 3.01}, {1.01, 1.01}, {5.01, 5.01}, {4.01, 4.01}}}, 
   {3, {{1.02, 1.02}, {3.02, 3.02}, {4.02, 4.02}, {6.02, 6.01}, {5.02, 5.02}}}, 
   {4, {{7.00, 7.00}, {1.03, 1.03}, {6.03, 6.03}}}, 
   {5, {{1.50, 1.50}, {4.04, 4.04}, {6.04, 6.04}, {7.04, 7.04}, {4.04, 4.04}}}, 
   {6, {{1.51, 1.51}, {4.05, 4.05}, {7.03, 7.03}, {6.05, 6.05}}}, 
   {7, {{2.50, 2.50}, {7.00, 7.00}, {5.01, 5.01}, {4.03, 4.03}, {8.01, 8.01}}}, 
   {8, {{2.51, 2.51}, {6.00, 6.00}, {7.01, 7.01}, {4.04, 4.04}, {8.02, 8.02}}}};

data = 
  Catenate[Transpose[{ConstantArray[#[[1]], Length[#[[2]]]], #[[2]]}] & /@ rawData]
```

> ```
> {{1, {1., 1.}}, {1, {2., 2.}}, {1, {3., 3.}}, {1, {4., 4.}}, {1, {5., 5.}}, 
>  {2, {2.01, 2.01}}, {2, {3.01, 3.01}}, {2, {1.01, 1.01}}, {2, {5.01, 5.01}}, 
>  {2, {4.01, 4.01}}, 
>  {3, {1.02, 1.02}}, {3, {3.02, 3.02}}, {3, {4.02, 4.02}}, {3, {6.02, 6.01}}, 
>  {3, {5.02, 5.02}}, 
>  {4, {7., 7.}}, {4, {1.03, 1.03}}, {4, {6.03, 6.03}}, 
>  {5, {1.5, 1.5}}, {5, {4.04, 4.04}}, {5, {6.04, 6.04}}, {5, {7.04, 7.04}}, 
>  {5, {4.04, 4.04}}, 
>  {6, {1.51, 1.51}}, {6, {4.05, 4.05}}, {6, {7.03, 7.03}}, {6, {6.05, 6.05}}, 
>  {7, {2.5, 2.5}}, {7, {7., 7.}}, {7, {5.01, 5.01}}, {7, {4.03, 4.03}}, 
>  {7, {8.01, 8.01}}, 
>  {8, {2.51, 2.51}}, {8, {6., 6.}}, {8, {7.01, 7.01}}, {8, {4.04, 4.04}}, 
>  {8, {8.02, 8.02}}}
> ```

```
c =
  ClusterClassify[data, 
    DistanceFunction -> (EuclideanDistance[Last[#1], Last[#2]] &)]
```

[image]

```
clusters = GatherBy[data, c]
```

> ```
> {{{1, {1., 1.}}, {2, {1.01, 1.01}}, {3, {1.02, 1.02}}, {4, {1.03, 1.03}}}, 
>  {{1, {2., 2.}}, {2, {2.01, 2.01}}}, 
>  {{1, {3., 3.}}, {2, {3.01, 3.01}}, {3, {3.02, 3.02}}}, 
>  {{1, {4., 4.}}, {2, {4.01, 4.01}}, {3, {4.02, 4.02}}, {5, {4.04, 4.04}}, 
>   {5, {4.04, 4.04}}, {6, {4.05, 4.05}}, {7, {4.03, 4.03}}, {8, {4.04, 4.04}}}, 
>  {{1, {5., 5.}}, {2, {5.01, 5.01}}, {3, {5.02, 5.02}}, {7, {5.01, 5.01}}}, 
>  {{3, {6.02, 6.01}}, {4, {6.03, 6.03}}, {5, {6.04, 6.04}}, {6, 6.05, 6.05}}, 
>   {8, {6., 6.}}}, 
>  {{4, {7., 7.}}, {5, {7.04, 7.04}}, {6, {7.03, 7.03}}, {7, {7., 7.}}, 
>   {8, {7.01, 7.01}}}, 
>  {{5, {1.5, 1.5}}, {6, {1.51, 1.51}}}, 
>  {{7, {2.5, 2.5}}, {8, {2.51, 2.51}}}, 
>  {{7, {8.01, 8.01}}, {8, {8.02, 8.02}}}}
> ```

Comment: I tried your code with the following data https://pastebin.com/rEzbC1kH. Here I have 5 sub-lists, whereby: `Length@rawData[[#, 2, All]] & /@ Range@Length@rawData = {443, 443, 444, 442, 443}`. For this **`clusters = GatherBy[data, c]` took very long (90 min**, macbook pro, 2,7 GHz i7, 16GB Ram). The line `c =ClusterClassify ...` needs about 1 min. The **calculated clusters** are here: https://pastebin.com/XBiRQcWW and they look **excellent**. My problem: **In reality where I have about 500 coordinates per sub-set and about 1000 sub-sets `GatherBy` would last for many days.** What can I do?

Comment: @mrz. It might go faster with a training set that is only fractional sample of the complete data. Of course, a smaller sample risks less accuracy in the clustering. That is a trade-off that must be made when machine learning brought into play.

Comment: @mrz. I can't act as your personal tutor. Read the docs on `ClusterClassify` and `GatherBy` do. If you can't reach an understanding that make you confident in their use, seek another method.

Comment: I will do that ... thank you very much for your help and this solution.

Answer (score 3):

You may use [`GatherBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GatherBy.html) with [`Floor`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Floor.html) to collect the coordinates into nearest sets.  Then [`Split`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Split.html) these into consecutive runs.

With `list` as defined in OP and

```
coords = Flatten[Function[{i, v}, Join[{i}, {#}] & /@ v] @@@ list, 1];
```

Then

```
Sequence @@ Split[#, First@#2 - First@#1 <= 1 &] & /@
  GatherBy[coords, Floor[#[[-1]], .2] &] //
 SortBy[First]
```

> ```
> {{{1,{1.,1.}},{2,{1.01,1.01}},{3,{1.02,1.02}},{4,{1.03,1.03}}},
>  {{1,{2.,2.}},{2,{2.01,2.01}}},
>  {{1,{3.,3.}},{2,{3.01,3.01}},{3,{3.02,3.02}}},
>  {{1,{4.,4.}},{2,{4.01,4.01}},{3,{4.02,4.02}}},
>  {{1,{5.,5.}},{2,{5.01,5.01}},{3,{5.02,5.02}}},
>  {{3,{6.02,6.02}},{4,{6.03,6.03}},{5,{6.04,6.04}},{6,{6.05,6.05}}},
>  {{4,{7.,7.}},{5,{7.04,7.04}},{6,{7.03,7.03}},{7,{7.,7.}},{8,{7.01,7.01}}},
>  {{5,{1.5,1.5}},{6,{1.51,1.51}}},
>  {{5,{4.04,4.04}},{5,{4.04,4.04}},{6,{4.05,4.05}},{7,{4.03,4.03}},{8,{4.04,4.04}}},
>  {{7,{2.5,2.5}},{8,{2.51,2.51}}},
>  {{7,{5.01,5.01}}},
>  {{7,{8.01,8.01}},{8,{8.02,8.02}}}}
> ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think `Thread /@ list` is simpler than your `Function[{i, v}, Join[{i}, {#}]& /@ v] @@@ list`. As for your algorithm, it works well if all points on the track have the same floor, but if the track extends far enough that they don't all have the same floor, then it doesn't work. For instance, try using a threshold of `.03` instead of `.2`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help ... I corrected an error in list which affects the tracks. Please see the short paragraph "Background information"  which I added to the question.

Answer (score 3):

Using [`RelationGraph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RelationGraph.html):

```
rg = RelationGraph[
  Abs[#1[[1]] - #2[[1]]] == 1 && 
    Abs[#1[[2, 2]] - #2[[2, 2]]] <= 0.2 &, Join @@ (Thread /@ list)]
SortBy[ConnectedComponents[rg], {#[[1, 1]], #[[1, 2, 1]]} &] // Column
```

[image]

Comment: Such a short code for I thought a complicated question, incredible ... thank you very much.

Comment: I haven't used `RelationGraph` before ... thank you very much for the solution.

Comment: @mrz  i may not have completely understood your aim but RelationGraph seemed a useful start. It may be ok for modest size problem.