# Removing anomalous points from data

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering, coordinate-transformation, geometric-transform

I have two sets of 2d-data points which can be transformed in each other by using a certain transformation function.

The problem is that in both data sets there are points which do not have associated points in the other list.

```
data1 = 
{
{33.9168, 631.006}, {48.8067, 673.198}, {3.59394, 671.167},
{64.1931, 632.506}, {58.7559, 613.401}, {5.45129, 635.602}, 
{40, 500}, {55.6619, 651.298}, {40, 850}, {18.1513, 671.949},
{54.6781, 598.251}, {23.5348, 608.289}, {65.0549, 531.442},
{74.4132, 479.425}, {32.9808, 671.931}, {46.4516, 750.192},
{26.9262, 650.35}, {27.1816, 413.334}, {20.3858, 633.391}, 
{50.9284, 770.49}, {64.1628, 670.801}, {13.1805, 652.588}, 
{41.4876, 650.752}, {82.9996, 514.631}, {36.0045, 612.007},
{26.4914, 548.723}, {58.3295, 458.015}, {21.557, 801.607}, 
{5.84689, 800.425}
};

data2 = 
{
{1532.93, 536.587}, {1514.13, 789.}, {1530.22, 596.423}, 
{1520.66, 640.844}, {1540.5, 660.237}, {1530.03, 790.2}, 
{1559.17, 758.9}, {1556.15, 661.154}, {1580.39, 467.111}, 
{1525.63, 660.167}, {1571.44, 620.556}, {1512.62, 623.985}, 
{1520, 500}, {1533.79, 638.607}, {1526.88, 621.69}, 
{1560.9, 586.053}, {1572.13, 658.656}, {1548.37, 638.933}, 
{1532.8, 400.935}, {1540.44, 618.794}, {1590.15, 501.882}, 
{1554.5, 738.5}, {1564.73, 445.615}, {1543.06, 600.093}, 
{1565.69, 601.532}, {1562.55, 639.132}, {1511.34, 659.395}, 
{1580, 400}, {1585, 700}, {1571.9, 519.25}
};
```

[image]

In the upper plots I have marked these particular points.

> **I have two questions**
>
> 1. How can I remove these marked non-associated points?
> 2. How can I sort the remaining points (in `data1corrected` and `data2corrected`, see below) in such a way that the first point of
>      `data1corrected` is corresponding to the first point `data2corrected`
>      and so on.

For question 1 I think I should calculate all the point-distances of `data1` and then separately of `data2`. I expect it should be possible to find from this distances-information the additional anomalous points and remove them.

The distance from each point to another point of `data1corrected` is aproximately the same as for the points of `data2corrected`.

For question 2 I have no idea.

I wish then to receive e.g. for the corrected lists:

```
data1corrected=
{
{21.557, 801.607}, {5.84689, 800.425}, {50.9284, 770.49}, 
{46.4516, 750.192}, {32.9808, 671.931}, {48.8067, 673.198}, 
{3.59394, 671.167}, {18.1513, 671.949}, {64.1628, 670.801}, 
{13.1805, 652.588}, {55.6619, 651.298}, {26.9262, 650.35}, 
{41.4876, 650.752}, {5.45129, 635.602}, {20.3858, 633.391}, 
{64.1931, 632.506}, {33.9168, 631.006}, {58.7559, 613.401}, 
{36.0045, 612.007}, {23.5348, 608.289}, {54.6781, 598.251}, 
{26.4914, 548.723}, {65.0549, 531.442}, {82.9996, 514.631}, 
{74.4132, 479.425}, {58.3295, 458.015}, {27.1816, 413.334}
};

data2corrected=
{
{1530.03, 790.2}, {1514.13, 789.}, {1559.17, 758.9}, 
{1554.5, 738.5}, {1540.5, 660.237}, {1556.15, 661.154}, 
{1511.34, 659.395}, {1525.63, 660.167}, {1572.13, 658.656}, 
{1520.66, 640.844}, {1562.55, 639.132}, {1533.79, 638.607},     
{1548.37, 638.933}, {1512.62, 623.985}, {1526.88, 621.69},   
{1571.44, 620.556}, {1540.44, 618.794}, {1565.69, 601.532}, 
{1543.06, 600.093}, {1530.22, 596.423}, {1560.9, 586.053}, 
{1532.93, 536.587}, {1571.9, 519.25}, {1590.15, 501.882}, 
{1580.39, 467.111}, {1564.73, 445.615}, {1532.8, 400.935}
};
```

[image]

Comment: How do you know which points should be removed? How did you find them?

Comment: @Alex Trounev: **Without the points wihich should be removed you can see from the uppermost two plots that the points of `data1` (red) and `data2` (blue) are scattered in the same "structure" with nearly same distances among each other in `data1` and `data2`**.  In the example `data2` are shifted to higher `x` coordinates and have also a small shift in `y` direction. The marked points have no "associated" partner points in the two plots. The shift in `x` and `y` could be also of the same size.

Comment: Maybe rescale to have ommon x axes and then use `Complement` with some `SameTest` to allow for modest numeric differences?

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau: yes the distances between all points of `data1` and of `data2` should a measure to find and remove the marked points. Do you mean that?

Comment: Basically yes. Could use `Nearest` functions from each set, checking that items in the other set come "close enough" to not be deleted as non-associates.

Comment: Where does the subject matter come into the picture?  I find it hard to believe that getting rid of "outliers" does not require any knowledge of the subject matter.  Could it be that the dataset "with" the "outlier" is not the problem but rather the dataset "without" the "outlier" is the problem?

Answer (score 6):

With the next three commands we rescale the data:

```
mmy = MinMax[Join[data1, data2][[All, 2]]];
rdata1 = Transpose[{Rescale[data1[[All, 1]]], Rescale[data1[[All, 2]], mmy, {0, 1}]}];
rdata2 = Transpose[{Rescale[data2[[All, 1]]], Rescale[data2[[All, 2]], mmy, {0, 1}]}];
```

Next we find the non-corresponding points as outliers of distances. (Using the package [OutlierIdentifiers.m](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/blob/master/OutlierIdentifiers.m).)

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/master/OutlierIdentifiers.m"]
```

To be more precise:

1. for each point `p` of the rescaled first dataset we find the distances from `p` to each point of the rescaled second dataset;
2. we find the minimum distance for each `p`;
3. we find the outliers with the obtained set of minimum distances;
4. we evaluate the found outliers to finally decide which points of the first dataset do not have associated points in the second dataset.

The procedure above is repeated with the roles of the two datasets reversed.

For the first dataset:

```
dists12 = Min /@ Outer[EuclideanDistance, rdata1, rdata2, 1];
pos12 = OutlierPosition[dists12, SPLUSQuartileIdentifierParameters]
dists12[[pos12]]

(* {7, 9, 18} *)

(* {0.201649, 0.251023, 0.0370386} *)
```

For the second dataset:

```
dists21 = Min /@ Outer[EuclideanDistance, rdata2, rdata1, 1];
pos21 = OutlierPosition[dists21, SPLUSQuartileIdentifierParameters]
dists21[[pos21]]

(* {13, 19, 28, 29} *)

(* {0.208751, 0.0370386, 0.177705, 0.183716} *)
```

**Note** that some of the found outliers might not be considered outliers -- edit `pos12` and `pos21` accordingly.

Here we plot the rescaled data and the found outliers (notice the tooltips):

```
ListPlot[{rdata1, rdata2, 
  MapThread[Tooltip, {rdata1[[pos12]], dists12[[pos12]]}], 
  MapThread[Tooltip, {rdata2[[pos21]], dists21[[pos21]]}]}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Gray, Lighter[Blue], {Darker[Green], PointSize[0.014]}, Red}, 
 PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend[{"rdata1", "rdata2", "rdata1 distance outliers", "rdata2 distance outliers"}],
 PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Large, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

[image]

Next we find the nearest points of the first dataset to any point from the second dataset using `Nearest`:

```
 nn1 = Nearest[rdata1 -> Range[Length[rdata1]]];
```

Tabulate the corresponding points after removing the outliers of second dataset (compare the y-coordinates):

```
Block[{cleanInds2 = Complement[Range[Length[data2]], pos21], pairs},
 pairs = Transpose[{data1[[First[nn1[#]] & /@ rdata2[[cleanInds2]]]], data2[[cleanInds2]]}];
 TableForm[Map[Append[#, EuclideanDistance @@ #[[All, 2]]] &, pairs], TableDepth -> 2]
]
```

[image]

Comment: For testing your solution I have changed the position of the old 2 outliers in `data1` and the 3 outliers in `data2`. The modified 2 points for `data1` are now `{42, 670}, {40, 650}` and the 3 points for `data2`are  `{1570, 750}, {1575, 480}, {1518, 650}`. Please see also https://pastebin.com/raw/WGjKj8ST (I have randomized the order). Why are now the added points `{40, 650}` corresponding to `{1548.37, 638.933}`and also `{13.1805, 652.588}` is corresponding to `{1518, 650}`?

Answer (score 5):

```
data1 = {{33.9168, 631.006}, {48.8067, 673.198}, {3.59394, 
    671.167}, {64.1931, 632.506}, {58.7559, 613.401}, {5.45129, 
    635.602}, {40, 500}, {55.6619, 651.298}, {40, 850}, {18.1513, 
    671.949}, {54.6781, 598.251}, {23.5348, 608.289}, {65.0549, 
    531.442}, {74.4132, 479.425}, {32.9808, 671.931}, {46.4516, 
    750.192}, {26.9262, 650.35}, {27.1816, 413.334}, {20.3858, 
    633.391}, {50.9284, 770.49}, {64.1628, 670.801}, {13.1805, 
    652.588}, {41.4876, 650.752}, {82.9996, 514.631}, {36.0045, 
    612.007}, {26.4914, 548.723}, {58.3295, 458.015}, {21.557, 
    801.607}, {5.84689, 800.425}};
```

I'll copy the data for completeness.

```
data2 = {{1532.93, 536.587}, {1514.13, 789.}, {1530.22, 
    596.423}, {1520.66, 640.844}, {1540.5, 660.237}, {1530.03, 
    790.2}, {1559.17, 758.9}, {1556.15, 661.154}, {1580.39, 
    467.111}, {1525.63, 660.167}, {1571.44, 620.556}, {1512.62, 
    623.985}, {1520, 500}, {1533.79, 638.607}, {1526.88, 
    621.69}, {1560.9, 586.053}, {1572.13, 658.656}, {1548.37, 
    638.933}, {1532.8, 400.935}, {1540.44, 618.794}, {1590.15, 
    501.882}, {1554.5, 738.5}, {1564.73, 445.615}, {1543.06, 
    600.093}, {1565.69, 601.532}, {1562.55, 639.132}, {1511.34, 
    659.395}, {1580, 400}, {1585, 700}, {1571.9, 519.25}};
```

Rescale to have x axis from 0 to 10, y axis from 0 to 1. The point is to penalize for x differences more than y differences.

```
scale = 10;
data1a = SortBy[data1, First];
{min1, max1} = MinMax[data1a[[All, 2]]];
data1b = Map[{scale (#[[1]] - data1a[[1, 1]])/(data1a[[-1, 1]] - 
         data1a[[1, 1]]), (#[[2]] - min1)/(max1 - min1)} &, data1a];
data2a = SortBy[data2, First];
{min2, max2} = MinMax[data2a[[All, 2]]];
data2b = Map[{scale (#[[1]] - data2a[[1, 1]])/(data2a[[-1, 1]] - 
         data2a[[1, 1]]), (#[[2]] - min2)/(max2 - min2)} &, data2a];
```

Here is how they look together.

```
ListPlot[{data1b, data2b}]
```

[image]

Form nearest functions for each. We could investigate distances to nearest neighbors, or make sure no index is required twice, etc. I do not actually make use of that.

```
nf1 = Nearest[data1b -> {"Index", "Distance"}];
nf2 = Nearest[data2b -> {"Index", "Distance"}];
```

Arbitrary cut-off: distance > 0.25.

```
distances1 = nf1[data2b, {Infinity, .25}];
distances2 = nf2[data1b, {Infinity, .25}];
```

Now check which indices in each set fail to have a sufficiently close neighbor.

```
Flatten[Position[distances1, {}]]
Flatten[Position[distances2, {}]]

(* Out[455]= {4, 27, 29}

Out[456]= {15, 16} *)
```

Automating this could be problematic since criteria might vary (how close on the x axis, how close on the y axis, which to remove when a closest neighbor is shared, etc.)

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Same comment as to Anton Antonov: Can you please show two data sets in which your code would fail, just that I understand where the limits are. E.g.: Would your code be able to find the outliers in such an example: i.imgur.com/K75oeID.jpg

Comment: If you post the data sets I can try it. Regardless, clearly there will be thresholds for which one might want different behavior from what this will deliver.

Comment: Would it be more stable to use instead of the distance the translation in `x` and `y` direction between `data1` and `data2`as a measure to find associated points (imagine the displacement  in `data1` and `data2` would be approximately the same)?

Comment: For testing your solution I have changed the position of the old 2 outliers in `data1` and the 3 outliers in `data2`. The modified 2 points for `data1` are now `{42, 670}, {40, 650}` and the 3 points for `data2`are  `{1570, 750}, {1575, 480}, {1518, 650}`. Please see also https://pastebin.com/raw/WGjKj8ST (I have randomized the order). I can play with the cut-off values but I am never able to find only these new outliers.

Comment: Yes, a different way to associate points might well be more stable.